# KeyError when selecting and modifying an element in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have 2 lists that I am iterating over, `english_tweets_2` and `truncated_trigrams_list`.

`english_tweets_2` contains tweets, stored as strings.
`truncated_trigrams_list` contains trigrams, also stored as strings.

I check if a trigram occurs in a tweet. If so, I use the trigram name to go to the corresponding column, and the tweet to go to the corresponding row. Then I increment that single value by 1, and repeat for all other combinations of tweets/trigrams.

```
# Create new columns, fill with 0 initially

for trigram in truncated_trigrams_list:
    tweet_features_en[trigram] = 0

# Increment columns depending on occurrence of trigram in tweet

for tweet in english_tweets_2:
    for trigram_name in truncated_trigrams_list:
        if trigram_name in tweet:
            tweet_features_en.loc[tweet][trigram_name] += 1
```

This gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'I love it when professors draw a big question mark next to my answer on an exam because I’m always like yeah I don’t either ¯\\_(?)_/¯'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-b400deacdb1b> in <module>
     17     for trigram_name in truncated_trigrams_list:
     18         if trigram_name in tweet:
---> 19             tweet_features_en.loc[tweet][trigram_name] += 1

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    877 
    878             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 879             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
    880 
    881     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: Tuple):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1108         # fall thru to straight lookup
   1109         self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1110         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1111 
   1112     def _get_slice_axis(self, slice_obj: slice, axis: int):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_label(self, label, axis)
   1057     def _get_label(self, label, axis: int):
   1058         # GH#5667 this will fail if the label is not present in the axis.
-> 1059         return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)
   1060 
   1061     def _handle_lowerdim_multi_index_axis0(self, tup: Tuple):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   3489             loc, new_index = self.index.get_loc_level(key, drop_level=drop_level)
   3490         else:
-> 3491             loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
   3492 
   3493             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'I love it when professors draw a big question mark next to my answer on an exam because I’m always like yeah I don’t either ¯\\_(?)_/¯'
```

The string in the keyerror `'I love it when professors draw a big question mark next to my answer on an exam because I’m always like yeah I don’t either ¯\\_(?)_/¯'` is one of the entries in the `english_tweets_2` list.

How do I get around this error? It is likely that my syntax is wrong, would love some help. Thank you!

Comment: better use `print()` to see what you get in variables. It seems you run `for`-loop to get index (which you try to use to get value) but it gives you directly value and you don't have to use it as `index`. B

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the structure of the dataframe, but I will assume that it is worth referring to the index with iloc:

```
for index, tweet in enumerate(english_tweets_2):
    for trigram_name in truncated_trigrams_list:
        if trigram_name in tweet:
            tweet_features_en.iloc[index][trigram_name] += 1
```

Comment: The dataframe contains several columns already, each representing a feature. The trigrams I am adding as additional columns serve as additional features. I think your method would mean I would have to add the number of preceding columns + index, like so - right?  `tweet_features_en.iloc[n + index][trigram_name] += 1`

Comment: No, the error occurs because you are referring to the name of a non-existent dataframe index 'tweet', but you need to use the numeric index or declare 'tweet' indexes